# How can I make this image transparent using Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I am using Adobe Photoshop version 13.0 (CS6) and I am trying to make this image transparent:

[image: b square]

I am trying to do something like layer --> new layer ..but it isn't working for me. I am very new to Photoshop so if someone could please explain how to make this image transparent, that would be very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. Understandable if you're new to this.

I think what you're trying to say is **"How can I make portions of this image *clear* and keep others the way they are?"** Right?

You need to select the areas you want to *knock out* then mask or delete them. I prefer the former whenever possible.

### Let's say you want the button shape pulled off of the dark grey background.

1. One solid option is the `Rounded Rectangle Tool`. Use it to draw a shape around your button. Notice my guessed `Radius` value for the corners. Adjust as necessary.

   [image]
   [image]
2. When you have your path where you want it, use this option in the `Layer` menu and you'll end up with a handy dandy *vector mask*. It shows up in your layers panel as shown below.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Now when you use `File` > `Save for Web & Devices ...` you can save to a PNG or gif file and check transparency to get something like this. (Forgive my inaccurate path, busy morning ;)

   [image]

Comment: well, I don't really care what the image opacity is like...I am just dealing with an error message when trying to opload the message.  Here is what the message reads like: "Image must not contain transparency. Non-opaque pixels detected"

Comment: Would you know how to fix that? And it seems it is talking about the entire image, no?

Comment: Your question says you are trying to make it *transparent*. Your comment says your trying to *remove* transparency. I'm confused. Where are you getting that message? Sounds like a service that doesn't support transparency.

Comment: I am trying to upload it to somewhere which will host my mobile app.  I just need to tweak the image so it stops getting this error.

Comment: We're going to need more info. If you want to do the opposite of your original question, you save with `Save for Web & Devices ...` and **uncheck** the `transparency` option.

Comment: @Genadinik Try choosing Flatten Image from the Layer Panel menu. Then save and upload... see if that works.

Comment: yes, I need to save it for the device - that sounds like what I probably need.  But when I go to save-as, I do not see the option of "save for web and devices" - how do I do that?

Comment: I also dont seem to have the flatten-image option.  Under what subsection is that?  Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Adobe changed the name again in CS6: Apparently, it's back to just `Save for Web` again.

Comment: When you `Save for Web` just un-check the `Transparency` option. Are you even trying this in Photoshop?

Comment: YESSSSSS that save-for-web thing did it - thank you 1 million...I was stressing big time because I was running out of time to do all the things I needed to do today!! You saved me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Seems like my actual answer was useless to you. I hope others find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In layers panel, you can change opacity of the selected layer (just above layers list). Change value to 60% for example.

Screenshot [here](http://www.signaturestop.com/tutorials/radiohead/9layerpanel.gif).

Comment: thank you, just to make sure I understand correctly, what should I choose from the layer menu?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the screenshot...I am more photoshop newb than you think :)

Comment: Ok, no problem. Go to "Window" => "Layers" in the menu of Photoshop or press F7 and you will be able to see layers panel like the screenshot.

Comment: Ok yes I brought up the layers panel. But should I made the entire image the layer? Or how does it work? :)

Comment: Just select the layer you want to see transparent by clicking on it and change opacity. For example, if you change opacity of all layers, your image goes to transparency. If you have difficulties with layers, learn because it's so important.

Comment: I am running into this very dumb issue here with my cursor: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/photoshop-how-to-get-my-cursor-back-to-normal

Comment: My cursor is a circle and I can not seem to select a part of the image :) LOL I feel like such an idiot.

Comment: Ok I got the cursor issue sorted, but what exactly do I have to do to make the whole image transparent? Or does that not make sense and only the background needs to be transparent?

Comment: I changed opacity to 60% but I still got the same error when uploading that image